# Loading an XML file with SQL*Loader or an external table

Tags: xml, oracle, oracle11g, sql-loader

I want to load an XML file with SQL*Loader in Oracle 11g Release 2 XE.

I've seen two ways:

**Example 1**

```
LOAD DATA infile * "str '</contact>'"
INSERT INTO TABLE address_book
TRUNCATE FIELDS(
 dummy1 filler char(2000) terminated BY "<contact>",
 contact_name char(2000) enclosed BY "<contact_name>" AND "</contact_name>",
 .....
)
BEGINDATA
.....
```

**Example 2**

Using an external table, as in the article [loading XML documents into an Oracle database](http://www.liberidu.com/blog/2014/07/18/loading-xml-documents-into-an-oracle-database/).

I don't understand; when you would use 1 and when you would use 2?
And are there also other ways to load XML through SQL*Loader?

Comment: The second way is using the SQL\*Loader driver, which isn't quite the same as the SQL\*Loader utility. Have you already read [Loading XML Content into Oracle XML DB](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb03usg.htm#ADXDB4048) and [External Table Concepts](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/et_concepts.htm)? Are you loading one file or lots of files; and into a staging table or straight into a real table? Is your XML file(s) on the server or a separate client machine?

Comment: I have the xml file on the computer and I would do the mapping to relational table, but I have to use sql loader to load files

Comment: I might write a script to parse the XML and convert the file to delimited or maybe even feed sqlldr directly through stdin.